# Angular 5 - Response HttpInterceptor - retry on timeout (504)

Tags: angular, observable, interceptor

I tried implementing an HttpInterceptor to retry requests that timeout. I implemented the following code, but err does not contain the status code, hence it doesn't work.

```
@Injectable()
export class RetryInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor() { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(req)
            .retryWhen(error => {
                return error
                    .flatMap((err) => {

                        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status === 504) { // timeout

                            return Observable.of(err.status).delay(5000);
                        }

                        return Observable.throw({ error: 'No retry' });
                    })
                    .take(1)
                    .concat(Observable.throw({ error: 'Sorry, there was an error (after 5 retries)' }));

            });
    }
}
```

The err object has the following object (notice that status is 0):

[image]

Devtools shows error 504:
[image]

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

---- UPDATE ----
After a deeper analysis I found out that the problem is that I have another interceptor that adds the Auth header to my requests. I created a stackblitz sample to show this problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-interceptors-azhwak
In the above example you can check that the error code is always 0 (zero), even though the error is 504. If you comment out the other interceptor (I2) the code works as expected.

Not sure if I am doing something wrong or if I shouldn't have multiple interceptors (some updating the request, and some the response)?

UPDATE 2

User @AngularInDepth.com was right, the problema was that CORS wasn't being provided. Managed to get it working using a different service. But now I am facing a different issue, I'd like to only call the second Interceptor (I2) after the first retry. Is there a way to do it?

See the updated example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-interceptors-ckbvsb

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to change the order of these interceptors? They are called on the same order as you add they.

Comment: @Fals Yes I have, as you can see on the stackblitz sample I provided the order has no effect. Only if I remove the second interceptor that the error code works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the service `https://httpstat.us/504` itself. It doesn't handle CORS correctly when you add a custom header to the request and hence the XHR request errors instead of making a request. When the XHR errors, you get a status of `0` because no request was made. [Here is the plunker](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-interceptors-tyziwz) that demonstrates that and the code:

```
request() {
    const url = 'https://httpstat.us/504';

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();  
    xhr.open('GET', url);      

    // when commented out `onload` handler is executed, otherwise `onerror`    
    // xhr.setRequestHeader('any', 'any');

    xhr.onload = () => {console.log('loaded')};
    xhr.onerror = () => {console.log('errror')};

    xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @AngularInDepth.com , you led me to the right place. I've updated the question with another case (only calling the second interceptor after retry has also failed). Could you help me with that? Thanks

Comment: @HobojoeBr, this seems to be a separate question? Can you please revert this one back and ask another one? I'll take a look

Comment: You are right @AngularInDepth. My bad. I have just created the new questions: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48865398/angular-5-interceptor-only-call-second-interceptor-after-failed-retry-on-first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48865398/angular-5-interceptor-only-call-second-interceptor-after-failed-retry-on-first)