# Angular 5 Interceptor - Only call second interceptor after failed retry on first interceptor

Tags: angular, rxjs, interceptor

I am building an angular 5 app where I have 2 interceptors:

- One to retry failed 504 requests
- Another to show error messages to users about failed requests

I want that the second interceptor only gets called when the error is not 504 or when it is 504 and has already been retried by the first interceptor.

I have created a sample with both interceptors: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-interceptors-ckbvsb

Hope to get some assistance!

Thanks

UPDATE:

Thanks everyone for your assistance! I have ended up implementing it like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class I1 implements HttpInterceptor {
 intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
 console.log('intercepted I1');

 return next.handle(req)
  .retryWhen(error => {
    return error
      .mergeMap((err, i) => {
        if (i > 0) return Observable.throw(err)
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status === 504) { // timeout
          return Observable.of(err).delay(5000);
        } else {
          return Observable.throw({ error: 'No retry', cause: err })
        }
      })
  });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is the order in which you provide the two interceptors. You are providing I1 first and then I2. This means that a request will flow through I1 → I2, but the *response* will flow through I2 and only then through I1. So just switch the order:

```js
@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, HttpClientModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: I2,               // <-- I2 first
            multi: true
        },
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: I1,               // <-- And only then I1
            multi: true
        }
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: Please read my answer again. It's about the order in which they are provided.

Comment: check the OP stackblitz, they are already in this order. that's not the problem here.

Comment: I don't know if we're looking at different links, but what I see on the posted Stackblitz is that I1 is first and I2 is second in `app.module.ts`.

Comment: @IngoBürk Changing the order seems to have fixed the problem. I didn't know about this way of processing responses. But how would I pass the HttpError to I2 after the retry? This way it only passes the message, but I would like to get the HttpErrorResponse on I2 as well. Thanks

Comment: @HobojoeBr, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48901048/2545680)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one way how it can be done - apply it to your code:

```
// an observable producer that produces an error
const producer = (obs) => {
    obs.next(0);
    obs.error(new Error('504'));
};

const i1 = Observable.create(producer).pipe(
    retryWhen((errors) => {
        return errors.pipe(
            scan((a, v, i) => {
                a.unshift(v);
                return a;
            }, []),
            map((v) => {
                if (!v[0].message.includes('504') || v.length > 1) {
                    throw v[0];
                } else {
                    return v[0].message;
                }
            }),
            delay(2000)
        )
    })
);
```

You can learn more about creating observables [here](https://indepth.dev/reference/rxjs).

Comment: Thanks! Your solution worked but I couldn't add the delay to it, probably because I am new to RXJS. But I am very greatful for your assistance!

Comment: @HobojoeBr, just add `delay` operator. I've updated my code. Your solution with `index` in `mergeMap` is probably easier to understand then mine :)

Comment: Great, I still have a long way to go with RxJs! Thanks

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com: Do you mind if you could have look at nearly the same issue I'm facing in the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50024524/how-to-handle-error-when-implementing-exponential-backoff-function?noredirect=1#comment87066773_50024524) please? I would like to implement your solution, but just can't figure out how to implement it in my code. Thanks

Comment: @k.vincent, I'll take a look when I have time

Answer (score -2):

I not sure that's the right way to handle this kind of things, interceptors are used to check requests, not responses, they dont care about the response returned because you pass the request with the .next before you even see the response.

seems more fitting to be done in a service that checks the response and then does another request to the other resource.

keep the retry interceptor in place and check the response you get on the service itself or the component to use a fallback URL.

Comment: Sorry Daniel, but you are wrong on this point. Angular 4.3+ interceptors can handle both requests and responses. It just basically transform the full cycle of a request ( request -> resposes ) in an observable of HttpEvent wich are typed as request or responses events. Just check this out : https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses

Comment: it will intercept the response but it wont halt the other interceptors because they try to process the same URL. once the interceptor calls .next.handle(req) it will pass to the next interceptor regardless of the response therefor its not the correct way to use interceptors.

Comment: But OP is only using `catch` in the second interceptor, so if the first interceptor catches specific errors already, executing the second one won't do anything. Also, retrying based on the response happens before the second interceptor sees the response, so this is perfectly sensible.

Comment: he is trying to modify the headers before he catches any errors, but it'll happen before he'll even get the 504 error so it'll add to every call.

Comment: @DanielNetzer sorry, i misunderstood your answer

Comment: no problem, I hope that the guy who downvoted will care to explain why he did that aswell.

Comment: Where are you reading anything about modifying headers? Neither the question nor the Stackblitz mention this.

Comment: its in the stackblitz commented out.

Comment: I ignore commented out code if it isn't even mentioned in the question. The question is about retrying a specific error and ultimately displaying an error for failed requests, so I see no connection to modifying headers there. But only OP knows for sure, I guess.

Comment: And for the record, I am not the one who downvoted this answer.

Comment: @DanielNetzer, was me but as you answered has not been edited I cant upvote it.